# Google Calendar API return null from deleted event

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I don't know if this is an issue of the API, anyway, I'm trying to get the information from a deleted event, as you know an event isn't really deleted from Google database.

So I make this code:

```
var service = GetService(); //service for interact with API
Event result = service.Events.Get("primary", id).Execute();
return result;
```

If the event exist I can see all the information as `Start, End, Description` and so on; but if an event is deleted all these fields are null.

What happen?

Comment: what makes you think it's not `really deleted`?

Comment: @muratgu 'cause in the API exist a method, in particular this: `var request = service.Events.List("primary"); request.ShowDeleted = true;` that allow the developer to see the list of deleted events. And I can see the id of deleted event. The problem's that I cannot get the details of deleted event.

Comment: Have you tried logging the result to verify if it is `null`? Tried it on my calendar, it did not get a null value for `Start,End,Description` and it has a status `cancelled`.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I finally figure out of this. Seems that if you delete an event and this is moved in the trash, so you can see again the description properties. But if you delete the event also in the trash, all the properties are null. Try it yourself.